# PHP fmod problem

Tags: php

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$y = 5;
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
if (fmod($i, $y) == 0) {
    echo '<tr>';
}
?>
```

What i'm doing wrong? I want every 5 time to show the `<tr>`,any help?

Comment: if you change "y" be "$y" does that fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see where you increment $i; nor why you are using `fmod` instead of `%` (`fmod` is only for floating-point moduli). Try this code:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$y = 5;
while (have_posts())
{
  the_post();
  if ($i % $y == 0) echo '<tr>';
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a typo, or did you overlook the missing dollar sign in your y variable?  It should be $y.